# Using Hudson Continuous Integration, can I track build status separately for each branch without manually adding jobs for each branch?

Tags: java, git, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous

We're using git for version control and the workflow is such that people do their work in a branch.  In order to benefit from CI in that branch we want Hudson to build it and test it.  However, just because the branch is broken doesn't mean the whole build is broken.

Thus, I'm wondering if I could tell Hudson to report build status separately for every branch rather than a single build status.

I'm aware that I can create a new job for each branch manually but its cumbersome and error-prone.  I'd like something more automatic.

I'm wondering if there's a plugin, setting, or script for Hudson that would do this for me.

OR if there is a decent alternative to Hudson that would do so.

Comment: I fought this same problem, ended up just building seperate projects for each one in a branch, and using a view to see the build status of each branch.

Comment: Would it would it work as a matrix build? You still need to manually add and remove branches. But you might be able to see what branch was the bad guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to best divide jobs depends on how you're using branches. In our svn-based system, we have branches for each product release, so it's natural to have a separate job for each branch. I can understand the issue if you have lots of feature branches. There are some tips on the [git plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin) page for managing a stable integration branch.

Can you describe more specifically what's cumbersome and error-prone? Perhaps there are plugins or Hudson tips that can make it easier.

Here are a couple tips for job creation:

- You can set up a template job from which new branch jobs can be copied to make creation easier.
- Your template job can use a build parameter to specify the branch. That makes it easier to modify a value in one place and use it in several (e.g. in the checkout and passed into the build).
- If branch creation is frequent, you can automate the corresponding job creation through the [Hudson Remote API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API) (see also http://your-hudson-server/api)

---

**Update**: this [git post-receive hook script](http://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-hudson) (found by @Dobes) provides an automated way to create a job in Hudson when a branch is created in git.

Comment: The API approach does seem promising, perhaps I could create a Hudson job that scans the list of branches and adds jobs for any new branch it finds.  Perhaps someone out there has seen such a script already?  Some googling hasn't turned anything up.

Comment: I found something here that looks promising, maybe I'll try and use that: http://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-hudson

Comment: Yeah although it runs as a post-commit hook on git repo.  I think I'll be making one that runs as a java command so I can run it as a Hudson job instead.

Comment: Got a little github project going to create a job for each project based on a template.  It's rough around the edges but its working OK: https://github.com/wlicpsc/Git_Hudson_Sync